# Cordova for iOS ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store-connect

I created a fresh **Cordova for iOS** project trough the CLI and opened it in Xcode. 
After choosing **Archive** -> **Distibute** this error comes up at the end of the uploading to the AppStore process.

> ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not
>   contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120'
>   pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

**Setup:**

- Cordova Version: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
- Xcode Version: 11.2.1
- macOS Version: 10.15

config.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Example</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
   <platform name="ios">
   <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <!-- iPad Pro -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" height="167" />
        <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87" />
        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
        <!-- iPad Pro -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />     
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

CLI commands:

```
cordova create example com.example.app Example
(cd example)
cordova platform add ios 
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova-icon
cordova-splash
```

What I tried: Clean up build folder / Update Node/NPM  / Update Xcode

Every icon is in the image assets folder. How to fix this error?

Comment: paste your config.xml or at least the part for ios icons

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, done

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing references for all icons. This is what you need to have in your config.xml for all icons to be set, in the ios node

```
    <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-29.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="48" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-48.png" width="48" />
    <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="55" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-55.png" width="55" />
    <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-58.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-80.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-87.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="88" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-88.png" width="88" />
    <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-100.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-114.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-120.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-144.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-152.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="172" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-172.png" width="172" />
    <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-180.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="196" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-196.png" width="196" />
    <icon height="216" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-216.png" width="216" />
    <icon height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
```

Comment: Do I need to create the res/icons/ios folder in root?

Comment: res folder should already be present in the root of the cordova project

Comment: It's not present for my freshly build project. Did that change for the latest Cordova version or what am I missing?

Comment: Never moved, it is missing but you can create it by hand, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Tried it, still running into the same error. What settings do I need to choose for "App Icons and Launch Images"?